# Matplotlib: bar plot for selected value only

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, pandas-groupby

I have a dataFrame with different amounts and currencies.

```
Index      Date       Amount    Currency
0       2020-04-04     -2.95      CHF
1       2020-04-04    -56.20      EUR
2       2020-04-04     -7.00      USD
...         ...         ...       ...   
2082    2018-06-26    -24.00      COP
2086    2018-06-25   -625.00      GBP
```

I group values based on currency and date and then plot bar chart. This is all fine:

```
df.groupby(['Currency', 'Date']).Amount.sum().unstack(0).plot.bar()
```

in next step I would like to plot individual bar charts for each currency --> 5 bar charts for 5 currencies.

How do I define what single currency should be used in bar chart plot?

Comment: just pass `subplots=True` into `bar()`.

Comment: is there another way then subplots? If I have 20 currencies I would end up with 20 subplots. Is it possible to pass an argument to define what currency I want to plot in a bar chart?